# How to make a signed APK in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, apk

Dear All,

I have successfully made an application using Sencha touch 2 it's
 working fine in my Android device, also on Tablet and emulator. But
 the problem is that the apk file could not be uploaded on Android Market it shows
 me a error:

```
.apk is not signed also validity year 50 Error in Google market -: 
Google Play does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. 
Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.
```

I have changed my certificate also "configuration":"Release"
but not get any success. Dear i am also sharing my whole configuration
 file. If you find any of the error inside the configuration file
 please let me know about it.  Any of the suggestion is appreciated.
 Thank in advance.

> **Code in Configuration file is that-:**

```
{
"applicationName":"navi",
"applicationId":"com.amit.navi",
"versionString":"1.0",
"iconName":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
"inputPath":"build/native",
"outputPath":"build/",
"configuration":"Release",
"platform":"Android",
"deviceType":"Universal",
"certificatePath":"C:/Documents and Settings/amit/.android/amit.keystore",

"certificateAlias":"alias_name",
"sdkPath":"C:/android-sdk",

"orientations": [
"portrait",
"landscapeLeft",
"landscapeRight",
"portraitUpsideDown"
]
}
```

Comment: sir, i am facing same issue how can resolve this issue? Please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335714/how-to-sign-a-apk-developed-on-sencha-touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guide to creating a key to sign your apk with.
You have currently signed your app with a debug key and need to generate a new one using keytool (java tool) then sign your apk with that.
Sencha guide: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android

Keytool guide: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

the keytool is in your java directory