# How to sign a apk developed on sencha touch

Tags: android, sencha-touch, google-play

We have done mobile app in Sencha touch and then We have converted them to android apk file.I want to upload them in Play Store but when posting it to google play I knew I had to sign the application. anyone know how I can do this procedure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file